# When I try to connect to SQL SERVER using the raw string inside pyodbc.connect, it works, but if I try to pass the same string, it wont work

Tags: python, pyodbc

So,
I am trying to connect to SQL SERVER using this:
`conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver="SQL Server", Server="DESKTOP-UDM7FMJ", Database="TestDB", uid="sa", pwd="123456")`

That actually works just fine
[image]

But if I try to build the string like this

```
conn_info = r'Driver="SQL Server", Server="DESKTOP-UDM7FMJ", Database="TestDB", uid="sa", pwd="123456"'
  print (conn_info)
    
  conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_info)
```

Then I have issues. The print gives me the same string used previously.
[image]

However, I get the following error

```
  Message=('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
  Source=I:\Windows10\DatabaseHealth\PythonApplication2\Main.py
  StackTrace:
  File "I:\Windows10\DatabaseHealth\PythonApplication2\Main.py", line 16, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_info)
```

Why is that error showing up?

Comment: Your first example uses *keyword arguments* to the `.connect()` method, e.g., `Driver="SQL Server"`. Your second example includes double-quotes *within* the connection string, and that's wrong. It should be `r'Driver=SQL Server;…'`

Comment: I tried that, I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried passing the connection info using a dictionary rather than a string?

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact, I came to only pass the string after having issues with a dictionary. This is what I had for dict: conn_info = 'Driver="SQL Server", Database ="% s", Server="% s", uid=% s; pwd="% s"'% (params [0], params [1], params [2], params [3 ])

Comment: You're still putting double-quotes around the driver name and using commas instead of semi-colons. `'Driver="SQL Server", …'"` simply will not work.

Comment: Gord Thompson, that is not the problem. I tried with and without it.

Comment: `conn_info = 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=DESKTOP-UDM7FMJ;Database=TestDB;uid=sa;pwd=123456'`

Comment: Alright, Gordon, I see what you did now. Spaces between equal signs had to be removed as well. It works now. Thanks!